# Nodemailer - Error while sending mail: connect ETIMEDOUT 204.79.197.212:587

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I have disabled my firewall but I still get the same error, does someone have a solution

[2022-01-31 16:37:35] DEBUG Creating transport: nodemailer (6.7.2; +https://nodemailer.com/; SMTP/6.7.2[client:6.7.2])

[2022-01-31 16:37:35] DEBUG Sending mail using SMTP/6.7.2[client:6.7.2]

[2022-01-31 16:37:35] DEBUG [yeVtB39osUE] Resolved smtp.live.com as 204.79.197.212 [cache miss]

[2022-01-31 16:37:49] ERROR [yeVtB39osUE] connect ETIMEDOUT 204.79.197.212:587

[2022-01-31 16:37:49] DEBUG [yeVtB39osUE] Closing connection to the server using "destroy"

[2022-01-31 16:37:49] ERROR Send Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 204.79.197.212:587

Error while sending mail: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 204.79.197.212:587

Comment: I sent a request to this IP (port 80) and got `<h2>Our services aren't available right now</h2><p>We're working to restore all services as soon as possible. Please check back soon.</p>0AhP4YQAAAACIS5sejfnnTY1FBxNCOw8AR1JVMzBFREdFMDExOABFZGdl`. I think your provider got down.

Comment: @Giancarl021 Er, why would you expect a hostname specifically earmarked for SMTP to respond on port 80? The host is `smtp.live.com`, a Microsoft property - I would be shocked if their SMTP was actually down.

Comment: @esqew Fair enough. I didn't saw the `smtp.live.com`, my bad. About sending to port 80, why not? A timeout by itself does not give much information, it can be a lot of things. I was trying to see if I could get some hint from the server. Of course it probably have a reverse proxy and/or a load balancer that send to another server. But, as I haven't saw the url, I supposed it was a single server.

Comment: @Giancarl021 Security of a service operating on a scale akin to `live.com` would necessitate hardening of the infrastructure itself - it would be a completely unnecessary attack surface/risk to run any sort of material web service on infrastructure dedicated to SMTP.

Comment: @esqew I agree. But it responds to port 80. You can type the IP on the browser and try yourself.

Comment: I replaced  service: 'hotmail' with  host: "smtp-mail.outlook.com" and it somehow worked, thanks btw for the responses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit (april 2022) : this issue has been fixed in `nodemailer` v6.7.3 !

I’ve the exact same error !

I don’t know why, but using `smtp-mail.outlook.com` in place of `smpt.live.com` (which is used by default by nodemailer when you use the outlook/hotmail predefined service) works well and fix this error !

```js
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp-mail.outlook.com',
    port: 587,
    auth: {
        user: 'your-email-address',
        pass: 'your-password'
    }
})
```

Comment: Was having the issue in v6.7.1, even when using `smtp-mail.outlook.com`. Updating the version to latest(v6.7.7) fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

go to

Settings => View All Outlook settings => Mail => Sync email

here is info for your correct settings

[test image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ayif.png)